# Announcing the length of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var names=new Array("Charlie","Auggie","Hunter","Diesel","Harlum","Tank","Runt");
    var rnames=Math.floor(Math.random(1,names.length));
```

That is my code, rnames is always 0. How would I tell the length of a table?
(the length is 7 - in other words, i want to tell how many entries are inside of a table.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript, `Math.random()` doesn't take any parameters.
Any parameters you pass it are silently ignored, and it always returns a real number between 0 and 1.

Instead, you should multiply the number by the length of the array, like this:

```
var names = ["Charlie","Auggie","Hunter","Diesel","Harlum","Tank","Runt"];
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
```

Comment: In addition, Math.random()'s return value will always be between 0 and 1.

Comment: And, rchern, he said that in line 2 of his answer.

Comment: Since I cannot create another question for another 20 minutes, how do I do this? (I have 98 rep)
How do I create a line break in JavaScript? This is what I tried, but it did not work..
`box.value=rnames+"/n"+names[rnames];`

Comment: Given the way the site works, he could have added it after rchern posted the comment, and it wouldn't show up as an edit since it was within 5 minutes of being posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
var names=new Array("Charlie","Auggie","Hunter","Diesel","Harlum","Tank","Runt");
var rnames=Math.floor(Math.random()*names.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Math.random() takes any parameters. If you want an integer between two integres(min & max) try this

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

Regards,
Satyajit